# jQuery: Capture anchor href onclick and submit asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink, anchor

I almost never get to play with client-side stuff, and this presumably simple task is kicking my butt :)

I have some links. OnClick I want to prevent the default action, capture its href url, submit an ajax GET to that url, and simply `alert()` with the results  ...  but I can't even get past the starting line :)

Example anchors for play-time:

```
<a class="asynch_link" href="good/1.html">Click Here</a>
<a class="asynch_link" href="good/2.html">Click Here</a>
```

Now, I've played with a few suggestions for *similar* requests on SO, but the links still cause the browser to navigate to the href url.

Even with just

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function (event) 
    { 
         event.preventDefault(); 
         //here you can also do all sort of things 
    });
</script>
```

...the links still navigate to the other page.

I'm kinda feeling like and infant here :)

Any and all help will be deeply appreciated.

And, yes, I ***AM*** including jQuery :)
`<script src="//67.20.99.206/javascripts/jqueryCountdown/1-5-11/jquery.countdown.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: `jquery.countdown.js` appears to be a jQuery plugin. Are you including the full jQuery library as well? Such as http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS !!!!!  ... I copied/pasted the wrong line into my sandbox ... hahaha ... oh, I'm totally blushing rt now .. whooooh boy ... Thanks-a-bunch! :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false; // for good measure
});
```

Comment: I know this is years old, but it helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Try this

```
$('a').click(function (event) 
{ 
   event.preventDefault(); 

   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $.get(url, function(data) {
     alert(data);
    });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks. You put me on the right path. For some reason, nothing was getting returned, so I switched the `get` out and put together an `ajax` call and got everything working (much like what @sushanth ended up suggesting) ... thanks-a-bunch

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the Events **are not being attached** to your element because they are not being bound in DOM ready event . Try including your events in DOM ready event and if it works you will see the alert

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
         $('a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('fff')
        //here you can also do all sort of things 
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

After this send the Ajax request and submit the form in the Success callback function..

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
         $('a').click(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                 url: 'url',
                 dataType :'json',
                 data : '{}',
                 success :  function(data){
                     // Your Code here

                     $('#form').submit();
                 }
             })
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very similar to what I ended up with.  I have no form, and therefore no submit ... but this is the right idea. Thanks again :)