# How do browsers display the target url of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

If you do a google search for some string , the browser would render the search results in the form of clickable links. Now here comes my question. If one hovers on those links, at the bottom left hand side, you would be able to see the location where the browser would take you if you hit it. I want to know how the browser does it.

I dont think that search results are actually HTML based anchor tags. Atleast that's what I feel. But even in those cases, the target url gets displayed whenever we hover over the links.

Please share your thoughts on how its done..i need to do the same in a js code.

-->Thanks for your answers. There is a reason why I had to ask this. I have to enable drag and drop between a web page which i am gonna show in an SWT Browser and a java GUI. In order to do that, in the mousedown event, i am firing a javascript code. This basically gets the HREF attribute on the anchor element which the user has clicked. ****Now here is the catch. If I open google.com and if I do a mouse down IMAGE,YOUTUBE,GMAIL,DRIVE links the target URL is coming up fine. But if i try to do a mouse down on any of the results in google search OR in our original thin client application which we need to enable for drag and drop, the link is not coming up. However, the browser at the bottom shows the target link. I am confused. This is the reason why I think it is not an anchor tag.

I tried by registering an onmousedown with the following code for all the anchor elements. But with this if the user does a mousedown on any of the search result...no alert box was coming up.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
{
    elements[i].onmousedown = function()
    { 
          alert(this.getAttribute('href'));
    }
}
```

Comment: `window.status`... at least IE's of old worked like that

Comment: Did you look at the source code or the developer tools?

Comment: I have heard google has a javascript on their sites that explicitely displays the target url, when you move the mouse over a link

Comment: It *is* just a regular link.  Have a look at the source code yourself.

Comment: do you mean like this?:http://jsfiddle.net/73FhL/1/

Answer (score 3):

> I dont think that search results are actually HTML based anchor tags. Atleast that's what I feel.

You feel wrong. Search results are `<a>` elements.

> But even in those cases, the target url gets displayed whenever we hover over the links.

The browser has to know where the link goes. It can make its UI do pretty much anything it likes.

> Please share your thoughts on how its done..

With native code

> i need to do the same in a js code.

`window.status = element.href` in a mouseover event.

Some browsers will block this these days as it is too useful a technique for a phishing attack (to trick the user into going somewhere other than where they expect to go).

Comment: Smooth answer +1 - couldn't sum it up faster with my average english :)

Comment: Altering `window.status` does nothing in Firefox, Chrome, or IE 9 (and possibly earlier).

Comment: "Some" might have been understating things a little :)

Comment: @Quentin I have added some additional info. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

Search engine results, at least from google, are rendered as html anchor tags. No need to guess check the html source of the search page.

So the part about showing the link in the status bar on hover, that is standard behavior (I see a url to your SO profile when I hover on your name).

I'm going to take a leap and assume what you want to figure out, is how to render a link as anchor tag, but still do some javascripty stuff, instead of the default anchor tag behavior. Like how google attaches tracking information to the url instead of just open the search result url in a tab.

To do that, you need to attach an event handler to the anchor tag to capture the ''click'' event, prevent propagation of the real click event, and do your stuff instead. So the HTML looks like an anchor tag, but when you click it, its all your javascript.

You'll find a lot of references to do this on questions like [jQuery: Capture anchor href onclick and submit asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648916/jquery-capture-anchor-href-onclick-and-submit-asynchronously) or just basic google search on how to trap anchor click / href event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have added additional info. Please check.

Comment: you're trying to do something with a page that its not designed for! links in Google's search results already have a on mouse down event handler. . which might happen with any other Web page also. You should rethink what you are trying to achieve, and figure out a way that doesnt rely on js of the original page

Comment: Akshya...I am not making use of existing js of google. I am writing or rather executing a js snippet from my java application.

Comment: But Google s js is being executed. and its handler is suppressing the event you want to capture. btw, its akshay not akshya.

Comment: But Akshay I need to incorporate drag and drop behavior. And for that i ned the url which the ser is gonna drag. And I do not see any way out of it :/

Answer (score 2):

You can change the status bar this way: The href is the text in the status bar and when the user clicks the link it is changed to the real url:

```
    <a href="status bar" onmousedown="this.href='real page';">Link</a>
```

Comment: +1 Dirty as hell! I can't believe its that easy to give the browser bull! but its obvious when you see it done.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code of a Google search page, you'll see the links have format

```
<a onmousedown="return rwt(...)" href="http://somelink.com/somepath/">...</a>
```

- Initially, the `href` property of the link is correct, so it shows up correctly on hover.
- However, it gets mutated at click-time by Google's `rwt` function, which changes the `href` property to a `http://www.google.com/url?...` URL.
- This mutation happens when the mouse is pressed *down* -- just before the browser follows the link (which happens when the button is released *up*).

You can observe this behavior easily by right-clicking on a result link and seeing the URL change on click.

Comment: additioanal info. added.Please check.